# How To Properly Include Miscellaneous File With Python Source Distribution

Tags: python, packaging

I am unable to get miscellaneous (non-Python) files to be include in a Python project with `pip install`.

I tried using `include_package_data = True` and `MANIFEST.in` in `setup()`, but it did not include the `.html` files I wanted.
I tried using `package_data` in `setup()` as well but same result.

The `data_files` in `setup()` works. But it doesn't copy the `.html` file to the `site-packages` folder, instead it just copy to the root of the environment with a folder name `resource` as specified in the configuration.

Any one have idea what I am missing here?

I have the following project structure

```
ProjectA
- res/
    - template_a.html
    - template_b.html
    - template_c.html
- tool/
    - __init__.py
    - modulea.py
- constant.py
- project_a.py
- ...
- MANIFEST.in
- setup.py
- ...
```

**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Read the contents of the README.md file
from pathlib import Path
current_directory = Path(__file__).parent
long_description = (current_directory/'README.md').read_text()

setup(
    name = 'project_a',
    version = '0.0.1',

    # Dependency
    install_requires = [
        'requests',
        ],

    # Metadata
    author = '',
    author_email = '',
    description = 'Project A.',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    packages = [
        'tool',
        ],
    py_modules = [
        'project_a',
        'constant',
        '...'
        ],
    # data_files = [
    #     ('resource', [
    #         'res/template_a.html',
    #         'res/template_b.html',
    #         'res/template_c.html',
    #         ]),
    #     ],
    python_requires = '>=3.7',
    # include_package_data = True,
    # package_data = {
    #     '': ['res/*.html']
    #     },
    )
```

**MANIFEST.in**

```
include res/*.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that `res` is not declared as part of packages - `package_data` only works for entities that have been included as part of `packages`.

The other issue is that declaration of `package_data` has an empty string as the key - it doesn't actually reference the root directory but package directories, and only for file paths at that.  It does not correspond the root directory of the `site-packages` (or `dist-packages`).

The `MANIFEST.in` file and `data_files` declaration in `setup.py` is not part of the required solution, and thus can be omitted.

To fix the issues, you will need to declare `res` as part of packages, and that `package_data` will need to reference that "package" as the root (to limit the include files) and a list of desired files (in this case, all the html files via the `*.html` glob syntax) to be part of the installation.  The corrected `setup.py` will need to include the changes to ensure `python setup.py bdist_wheel` include the files you wish to include into the package:

```
setup(
    name = 'project_a',
    # ...
    packages = [
        'tool',
        'res',  # add this
    ],
    # ...
    include_package_data = True,
    package_data = {
        'res': ['*.html'],   # include this; pairs with the entry in `packages`
        # alternatively, uncomment the following to include any
        # *.html files from any of the `packages` declared above, 
        # e.g tools/*.html and res/*.html will be included as tool 
        # and res are inside `packages`.
        # '': ['*.html'],
    },
)
```

Running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` should now produce:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
...
writing manifest file 'project_a.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
creating build/lib/res
copying res/template_a.html -> build/lib/res
copying res/template_b.html -> build/lib/res
copying res/template_c.html -> build/lib/res
...
copying build/lib/tool/modulea.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/tool
copying build/lib/project_a.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/res
copying build/lib/res/template_c.html -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/res
copying build/lib/res/template_a.html -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/res
copying build/lib/res/template_b.html -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/res
copying build/lib/constant.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
...
creating 'dist/project_a-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel' to it
adding 'constant.py'
adding 'project_a.py'
adding 'res/template_a.html'
adding 'res/template_b.html'
adding 'res/template_c.html'
adding 'tool/__init__.py'
adding 'tool/modulea.py'
adding 'project_a-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'project_a-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'project_a-0.0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'project_a-0.0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
```

Note that the additional output compared to the version without the `'res'` entries in `packages` and `package_data` have been bolded.  The resulting `.whl` file may then be found in `dist` and it may be used for installation (e.g. via `pip install -U dist/project_a-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`).

Comment: here's a question tho, adding `res` to `packages`, does that mean the folder will also need a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: also a follow up is for `package_data`, let's say i map it to `resource` instead of `res`, so the line will be `'resource': ['*.html']`, where does this mapping come into play?

Comment: To your first question, no, it does not need a `__init__.py`. Your second question: the mapping is a matter of telling which `packages` has additional data, so if you want to include `resource` you will need to follow the identical step for `'res'` as I have outlined above.  This is why it is often better to enclose all your packages inside a single namespace to keep things tidy, rather than having a number of random directories being spewed onto `site-packages`.

Comment: @YTKme I have updated the answer to fully correct my mis-remembering of what `'': [...]` does inside `package_data`, and to correctly point out that the issue is that `res` is missing from `packages`.